# Using angular.extend() for controllers and overriding functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, angular-controller

I'm using Angular 1.4.8 and am trying to extend a controller. Both the original controller and the extending controller are extremely similar, but there's a function I want to override in the extending controller.

```
angular.module('app').controller('ControllerOne', function() {

    var vm = this;

    vm.data = {};

    vm.callSayHello = function() {
        vm.sayHello();
    }

    vm.sayHello = function() {
        console.log('Hello from ControllerOne.');
    }
});

angular.module('app').controller('ControllerTwo', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    angular.extend(vm, $controller('OrdersAddController', { $scope: $scope }));

    // I do not want to override vm.callSayHello(), so I don't redeclare that function.

    // This is what I want to override.
    vm.sayHello = function() {
        console.log('Hello from ControllerTwo.');

        // Some other extra handling.
    }
}]);

<button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.callSayHello()">Click Me</button>
```

It looks like I can override the `ControllerOne` functions in `ControllerTwo`. But for this particular case, the function I want to override, `vm.sayHello()`, isn't directly called from an event like a click, but rather it's called by another function, `vm.callSayHello()`.

So what happens is that when `vm.callSayHello()` is invoked from either `ControllerOne` or `ControllerTwo`, that also calls `vm.sayHello()`, but it always calls the function on `ControllerOne` despite being redeclared in `ControllerTwo`.

Hopefully that makes sense. But is there a way to just override that `vm.sayHello()` function in `ControllerTwo`?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
function mySmth(vm, $scope) {
  // no vm = this
 vm.smth = ...
}
```

now:

```
function baseCtrl($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  mySmth(vm, $scope);
}

function etendedCtrl($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  mySmth(vm, $scope);
  vm.smth = ...// something new
}
```

But this is not fancy and actually nice advice is - just do not extend controllers... If you have common functions - put them to service or to separate controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read that people generally do not recommend extending controllers, but they were so close in functionality that I was hoping there was an acceptable way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript inheritance for ur approach,

```js
//controller 1
function ControllerOne() {
  this.data = {};
}

ControllerOne.prototype.callSayHello = function() {
  this.sayHello();
};

ControllerOne.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  console.log('Hello from ControllerOne.');
};

ControllerOne.$inject = [];

//controller 2
function ControllerTwo($scope) {

}

ControllerTwo.prototype = Object.create(ControllerOne.prototype);

ControllerTwo.constructor = ControllerTwo;

ControllerTwo.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  console.log('Hello from ControllerTwo.');
};

ControllerTwo.$inject = ['$scope'];


//angular controller
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ControllerOne', ControllerOne)
  .controller('ControllerTwo', ControllerTwo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ControllerOne as ctrl">
    <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.callSayHello()">Click Me (Ctrl 1)</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ControllerTwo as ctrl">
    <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.callSayHello()">Click Me (Ctrl 2)</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one. I was hoping to see this answer here.